# Is there an alternative to dynamic stored procedures?

Tags: t-sql

I hate buikding these for a variety of reasons; debugging, lack of execution plan, permissions issues, etc. Is there a viable alternative to building huge dynamic sql statements in a stored proc and then executing it?

Comment: Narrow down the scope of this question and give us a specific case to consider.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes avoid dynamic SQL by deleting rows from a temp table that I don't want.  But I'm not saying that this is best for performance - I work in a data warehouse more often than not where performance is second to other factors, like avoiding dynamic SQL.

Here is an example, for a report that calls for TOP x records, I choose the max, say 200, and simply delete the rest. (I.e., 200 is the maximum the report will ever need. I hope.)   So there will be, if the parameter's name is @Range:

```
SELECT TOP 200 
...

DELETE FROM #MyTemp where Counter > @Range
```

Comment: I know.  I'm not sure why that confused you.  The TOP command will not allow a variable, so at times dynamic SQL is used to resolve that issue.

Comment: I totally get it now, I made an example can improve your code. Removed my earlier posts and gave you a point for comming up with a good example.